# What does Proof. "function 1 = function 2 is trivially met" mean?

Tags: definition, systems-of-equations

I checked and found trivially mean not important or insignificant. In mathematics, when the proof condition is written "is trivially met", what does it mean? Why we have to proof the function that is insignificantly equal?

For example (from the paper I am reading),

**Proof.** *The condition G(h|h) = C(h) is trivially met. The criterion C(h) may be written as*
$$C(h) = Σ_fC_f(h) $$

Comment: It means that it is obvious or can be figured out with very little effort.

Comment: It usually means that it's so easy and obvious that it's not worth much attention. But it's a dangerous expression: what is easy and obvious is subjective, it may be not so obvious for others. And sometimes, it's used just out of laziness of an author unwilling to explain boring details. The snippet you cited is too short to decide that, though,

Comment: Note that whether something is trivial is subjective. I also find that I use "trivial" when I should've used "well-known", for instance about central results that are in no way easy to prove, but I've used the result and reflected on the proof so much that I don't ever have to think about it. For an easy example, $\sqrt2$ isn't trivially irrational, but "everyone" knows the proof.